# WKWebview load external script JS from iPhone's Document Directory

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, swift, wkwebview

I am planning to use ChartIQ.js downloaded from remote server to iOS application's document directory, then  load the downloaded ChartIQ.js adding it in  tag in my local HTML file and use it  in a WkWebview.

### Is this possible at all?

```
<script src="(Documents_Directory_Path)/chartiq.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 5):

I think you can try to resolve your problem through script injection, so remove script src referring and load it (once downloaded and saved in the Document Directory) from Swift code with **WKUserScript** (I removed file exceptions checks but it's better you'll add it):

```
let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString
let webConfig = WKWebViewConfiguration()
let chartiq_js = try? String(contentsOfFile: documentsPath.appendingPathComponent("chartiq.js"), encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
let script = WKUserScript(source: chartiq_js!, injectionTime: .atDocumentStart, forMainFrameOnly: false)
webConfig.userContentController.addUserScript(script)
wkWebV = WKWebView(frame: self.view.frame, configuration: webConfig)
```

You can check if the file has been correctly loaded using Safari Simulator debugger pointed to the iOS Simulator as soon as your WkWebview has been shown.

**UPDATE:**

You can also load local resources using [loadFileURL](https://developer.apple.com/reference/webkit/wkwebview/1414973-loadfileurl) function (only from IOS9):

```
let fileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: documentsPath.appendingPathComponent("index.html") as String) as URL
let filePath = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: documentsPath as String) as URL
wkWebV.loadFileURL(fileURL, allowingReadAccessTo: filePath)
```

**note**: in your html file you must refer to javascripts, images etc. only with a direct link:

```
<script src="chartiq.js"></script>
```

And, of course, all your files must be downloaded all in the same directory.

Comment: A very nice and detailed explanation .. +1